# Proving 1-1 correspondance

Tags: elementary-set-theory

This question is giving me headaches some time now. I tried to solve it using compositions of functions, but with no use. Any help would be appretiated.
If $f:{A}\rightarrow{B}$,$g:{B}\rightarrow{C}$,${C}\rightarrow{A}$ are 1-1, then $A\equiv{B}\equiv{C}$.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** Use the [Cantor–Schroeder–Bernstein theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schr%C3%B6der%E2%80%93Bernstein_theorem), together with the fact that the composite of any two injective functions is injective.

For a bigger hint, hover your mouse over the box below:

> Since $f : A \to B$ and $g : B \to C$ are injective, $g \circ f : A \to C$ is injective. As $h : C \to A$ is also injective, you have injections $A \to C$ and $C \to A$.

Answer (score 0):

$f:{A}\rightarrow{B}$ is $1-1$, so we have $|A|\leq |B|\ \ (I)$.

$g:{B}\rightarrow{C}$ is $1-1$, so we have $|B|\leq  |C|\ \ (II)$.

$h:{C}\rightarrow{A}$ is $1-1$, so we have $|C|\leq |A|\ \ (III)$.

$(I),(II),(III)\rightarrow A\equiv{B}\equiv{C}$.